# Regex to get specific Character after occurrence of a specific string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a Regex to get a value after 'New Serial Number'

Input String : `[EXT] EOL Resolved : 343250; Serial Number : OLD123 ; New Serial Number : NEW123; UPS Tracking Number : UPSTRN123;`

I need output to be 'NEW123'

Tried :

```
Match(%K00291;"(?<=New Serial Number :)(.*;)";true)
```

But I am getting output as : `NEW123; UPS Tracking Number : UPSTRN123;`

Comment: `(.*?;)` please, note `?` after `*`: as **few** as possible

Comment: getting output as NEW123; . I need only NEW123

Comment: In order to get rid of `;` you can either `.TrimEnd(';')` the match, or intruduce a *group*: `"(?<=New Serial Number :)(?<value>.*;)"` then get group value: `match.Groups["value"].Value`

Comment: `"(?<=New Serial Number\s*:\s*(\S+)"` seems to serve your needs. If the value you need contains spaces, you may replace `(\S+)` with `([^;]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.*?` (`*?` - zero or more but as **few as possible**) instead of `.*` (which ends up to the *last* `;`) in order to stop matching at the *nearest* `;`:

```
 ..."(?<=New Serial Number :)(.*?)(?=;)"...
```

Finally, if you don't want to *include* trailing `;` into match, let's put it as `(?=;)`

Comment: Thanks, I got the expected output